# Can we run node and apache both on same port

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I have a application in nodejs and PHP. For now i am using different both. 
Can i run node and apache both on same port **8080**

Is, there is any way to run any application both on 8080

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

An port is usually connected only to one application. So you have to use different ports.

**Proxy** -
But you could for example create an virtual host in apache and configure this host as proxy. In this configuration you could access the node.js server on the same port. The node.js server would run on another port.

Comment: you can also differentiate by ip-address. but maybe i didn't understand you, why do you actually want to have both on the same port?

Comment: Act i want to run node and apache on 8080

Comment: And why? How want you decide which one is delivering the content to the client?

Answer (score 0):

For TCP based applications, no. You can have only one application listening on a single port at time. If you had 2 network cards, you could have one application listen on the first IP and the second one on the second IP, both using port 8080.... but I doubt that is your case.

I guess you can run them on UDP protocol, which could allow you to have two applications listen to the same port, but as UDP is unreliable and it doesn't establish connection, just sends/receives packets. You might experience big packet loss on UDP.

So, short answer - no.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there might be a way using iptables. Add a rule of this nature

```
iptables -A INPUT \
 -p tcp  \
 -m bpf --bytecode "14,0 0 0 20,177"
 -j redirect .. Port 80
```

Check the first few bytes of the connection, and redirect the connection. Then you can accept both http and node.js on the same port, but have the servers running on separate ports.

The syntax above is incorrect, and I have not tried it, but I know people who have used this strategy successfully.